# I want to use streambuilder() and get the data from server only in firestore

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

Hi there I am using flutter firestore and I have dynamic data which change every second so I chose to user streabuilder(), but the problem that I get data from catch which I can't disable, any one have idea to how I can set stream from server side only

this my code :

```
      child: StreamBuilder(
          stream: firestore.collection("messages").snapshots(),
          builder: (context,snapShot){

            if(!snapShot.hasData) return Container();
            List<DocumentSnapshot> list = snapShot.data.documents;
            if(list.isNotEmpty){
              if(!list[0].metadata.isFromCache){
                return Container(

                );
              }
            }else{
              setState(() {

              });
            }
            return Container();
          },
        ),
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can specify the source for your stream:

```
firestore.collection("messages").getDocuments(source: Source.server).asStream(),
```